# Combinatoric Coefficients of a Polynomial

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, polynomials, summation

I have the following function:

$$f(x)=\left(T_{N_2}(x)-T_{N_1}(x)\right)\left(T_{N_3}(x)-T_{N_1}(x)\right)\left(T_{N_3}(x)-T_{N_2}(x)\right)$$

where $T_{N}(x)=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+...+\frac{x^N}{N!}$

Looking at the difference yields

$$T_{N_2}(x)-T_{N_1}(x)=\sum_{k=N_1+1}^{N_2}\frac{x^k}{k!}$$

Therefore my polynomial becomes

$$f(x)=\sum_{k=N_1+1}^{N_2}\frac{x^k}{k!}\sum_{k=N_1+1}^{N_3}\frac{x^k}{k!}\sum_{k=N_2+1}^{N_3}\frac{x^k}{k!}$$

I would like to simplify further from here, but i'm running into a problem.  For example, when $N_1=1, N_2=4,$ and $N_3=6$ the polynomial is

$$\frac{x^9}{2!2!5!}+\left(\frac{2}{2!3!5!}+\frac{1}{2!2!6!}\right)x^{10}+\left(\frac{2}{2!3!6!}+\frac{2}{2!4!5!}+\frac{1}{3!3!5!}\right)x^{11}+\left(\frac{2}{2!4!6!}+\frac{1}{2!5!5!}+\frac{2}{3!4!5!}+\frac{1}{3!3!6!}\right)x^{12}+\left(\frac{2}{2!5!6!}+\frac{1}{3!5!5!}+\frac{2}{3!4!6!}+\frac{1}{4!4!5!}\right)x^{13}+\left(\frac{1}{2!6!6!}+\frac{2}{3!5!6!}+\frac{1}{4!4!6!}+\frac{1}{4!5!5!}\right)x^{14}+\left(\frac{2}{4!5!6!}+\frac{1}{3!6!6!}\right)x^{15}+\frac{x^{16}}{4!6!6!}$$

There is a combinatorial argument, i think, to be had with the different denominators of the polynomial's coefficients, but I'm not sure what it is. Obviously the lowest degree coefficient's denominator is just $(N_1+1)!(N_1+1)!(N_2+1)!$ and a similar argument for the leading coefficient as well with $N_2!N_3!N_3!$

Is there any way to come up with a summation formula (could be a double or a triple) for this combinatorial argument?

Comment: Are you familiar with the stars and bars counting strategy?

Comment: I am sort of familiar.....

Comment: Do we know anything about the size of N1 relative to N2?

Comment: I'll set the condition that $N_1<N_2<N_3$.

Comment: Okay, as you said, the largest and smallest, coefficients are clear. If we rewrite the expression as one sum, we sum from 2N1 + N2 + 3 to N2 + 2N3. You have found the coefficient of the first and last terms of this new sum. Question: what is the coefficient of the second term of this new sum? The third term? Can you find a pattern using the stars and bars method?

Comment: Wait, why are you adding 3 to the lower bound?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19859/discussion-between-john-and-eleven-eleven).

Comment: Sorry I'm on my phone cannot talk in chat: (N1 + 1) + (N1 + 1) + (N2 + 1) = 2N1 + N2 + 3.

Comment: Oh yeah.  I was thinking the lower bounds were just $N1,N2,N3$.  I'm still not sure about stars and bars and how I can get the coefficients from there...

Comment: @John i was wondering if you had time to help still.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking your polynomial as [Exponential generating function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function#Exponential_generating_function), the coefficient of $\frac{x^n}{n!}$ in
$$
\left( \sum_{i=N_1 + 1}^{N_2}\frac{x^i}{i!} \right)
\left( \sum_{i=N_1 + 1}^{N_3}\frac{x^i}{i!} \right)
\left( \sum_{i=N_2 + 1}^{N_3}\frac{x^i}{i!} \right)
$$
is the number of ways to split a group of $n$ people into three groups, the first of size between $N_1+1$ and $N_2$, the second with size between $N_2 + 1$ and $N_3$, the third with size between $N_1$ and $N_3$.
You can write this as, e.g.
$$
\text{coeff of } \frac{x^n}{n!}
= \sum_{i=N_1 + 1}^{N_2} {n \choose i}
\sum_{j = \max(N_1 + 1, n - i - N_3)}^{\min(N_3, n - i - N_2 - 1)} {n - i \choose j}
$$
or with trinomial coefficients your function is
$$
\sum_{i = N_1 + 1}^{N_2} \sum_{j = N_1 + 1}^{N_3} \sum_{k = N_2 + 1}^{N_3}
{i + j + k \choose i, j, k} \frac{x^{i+j+k}}{(i+j+k)!}
$$
But it's really not going to get any cleaner than that.

Comment: So there is no "nice" way to get something of the form $$\sum_{n=2N_1+N_2+3}^{N_2+2N_3}\sum_{(i+j+k=n)}$$ or something like that?

Comment: Well the answer is
$$
\underbrace{\sum_{i = N_1 + 1}^{N_2} \sum_{j = N_1 + 1}^{N_3} \sum_{k = N_2 + 1}^{N_3}}_{i + j + k = n}
{i + j + k \choose i, j, k},
$$
if you consider that nice enough.